# Unwanted margins at top and bottom of screen

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a bit of trouble with UI in the loading screen of my app. The loading page shouldn't have any margin at the top and bottom

How it looks.

[image: LoadingScreen]

How I want it to look.

[image: LoadingScreen1]

This is the code:

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <BoxView HeightRequest="0.35" Color="{StaticResource DarkGrayColor}" />
    <Label Text="{helpers:Translate Cancel}" FontSize="Large" TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryDarkColor}"
        HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" />
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</StackLayout>
```

This code belongs to the bottom part of the loading screen.

I am new to XAML.

Comment: Hello, what is your problem? Could you please show the whole .xaml file?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this yourself, if you know which control is taking the extra space. 
 You should know `VerticalOptions` default value is `LayoutOptions.Fill` unless otherwise specified, I think this tip should resolve your problem. see which is the control at the bottom or which layout is wrapping your `StackLayout`

Here is what you can do to resolve it yourself:

Turn on Layout bounds to see the which control is taking how much space, this should help you in designing things in a better way.

Settings->Developer Options -> Show layout bounds

[image]